# Increase log length

Tags: logging, cloud, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

With

```
cf log APPNAME --recent
```

I can dump the last ~200 lines of the Loggreggator buffer. I am wondering how I could increase this limit or how I could save the logs elsewhere in order to take full control of my logs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once your application is deployed and somewhat stable you will want to
>   use a logging service.  There are a couple of reasons for wanting to
>   use a logging service.  The first reason is using cf logs appName
>   –recent will only allow you to see so far back in your logs.  The only
>   way to view logs of your app over a long period of time is to use a
>   logging service.

[Accessing Application Logs -> Using Persistent Logging Services](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/29/accessing-application-logs-bluemix/)

Don't worry about IBM Blumemix, it's also powered by CF, like the Swisscom App Cloud.

Swisscom offers ELK service for log history. With CF CLI client you don't have long term history.

see [ELK Realtime logging](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/elk.html)

> The ELK stack consisting of Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana gives
>   the power of centralising log data and provides real-time data
>   insights with intuitive dashboard and robust search capabilities.

See also blog posting with howto [ict.swisscom.ch](http://ict.swisscom.ch/2016/01/real-time-log-analytics-with-elk-powered-by-swisscom-application-cloud/)